# Packing taxonomy fields into one div not from SQL?

Tags: theming, 8

I created 2 taxonomy entity-reference fields. One is *Categories* and one is *Tags* and some similar other fields.

In nodes, some of these taxonomy fields appear one above the other.

I want to give some `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` css code, not to each one - but to all together.

Yet, they don't sit inside a wrapping div and wrapping them through the SQL isn't quite comfortable, though I am not sure it's a minimalist/easy to supervise/safe solution.

Do you know a way to bias Drupal 8 to "pack" some of these into a div ? Maybe an intervention in the Twig could do that with some behavior-code?

Answer (score 1):

This is the content of `field.html.twig` in the core theme `classy`:

```
{%
  set classes = [
    'field',
    'field--name-' ~ field_name|clean_class,
    'field--type-' ~ field_type|clean_class,
    'field--label-' ~ label_display,
  ]
%}

{%
  set title_classes = [
    'field__label',
    label_display == 'visually_hidden' ? 'visually-hidden',
  ]
%}

{% if label_hidden %}
  {% if multiple %}
    <div{{ attributes.addClass(classes, 'field__items') }}>
      {% for item in items %}
        <div{{ item.attributes.addClass('field__item') }}>{{ item.content }}</div>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
  {% else %}
```

Each field is packed into a div with its own class `field--name-field-name`. In your case `field--name-field-tags` and `field--name-field-categories`.

### Steps for solution:

1. If you don't use classy as base theme you can put somehting similar in your custom theme or simply copy this twig from the classy theme and change as needed.

   core/themes/classy/templates/field/field.html.twig -> themes/mytheme/templates/
2. Flush all cache.

Comment: If I represent these fields in field.html.twig Drupal will prefer how they are customized there? I understand right? If so its very cool !!! I am just not sure what should be copied since each of the 3 parts above seems to deal with something different, can you please gracefully elaborate just on that point? Thx.

Comment: You can copy the complete twig. The code example is only a part of it. See the edited answer

Answer (score 1):

Go to your theme's templates folder and edit node.html.twig

There, put:

```
<article{{ attributes }}>

  {{ title_prefix }}
  {% if not page %}
    <h2{{ title_attributes }}>
      <a href="{{ url }}" rel="bookmark">{{ label }}</a>
    </h2>
  {% endif %}
  {{ title_suffix }}

  {% if display_submitted %}
    <footer>
      {{ author_picture }}
      <div{{ author_attributes }}>
        {% trans %}Submitted by {{ author_name }} on {{ date }}{% endtrans %}
        {{ metadata }}
      </div>
    </footer>
  {% endif %}

  <div{{ content_attributes }}>

    {{ content|without('title','body', 'field_categories', 'field_tags', 'field_otherfield') }}

    {{ content.title }}
    {{ content.body }}
    <div class="some-wrapper">
       {{ content.field_categories }}
       {{ content.field_tags }}
    </div>
    {{ content.field_otherfield }} 

  </div>

</article>
```

That will print these fields as they presented on this twig file ---> Packed in a div.

### Notes:

- If you want them without the label use `{{ content.field_name[0] }}`.
- If you want only the label use `{{ content.field_name['#title'] }}`.
- As always with templates, flush the cache to see changes.

Comment: If you print single fields you should also print the rest of the content `{{ content|without('field1','field2',...) }}`. Otherwise you loose the caching data.

Comment: @4k4 I didn't know that, thx!

Comment: Hello @NoSssweat --- What I talk about deals with all content types... I need a global solution... I guess your shorten at least 40% of the answer in that case?...

Comment: @Benia then name it **node.html.twig** to affect all content types.

Comment: I will just use the existing one and put it under body tag. Should the code be different and shorter than appears? Could you please use the field names "categories" and "tags" in your answer? Thank you anyway!!

Comment: @Benia updated answer, you just print fields like this `{{ content.[machine_name] }}` you can find the machine name in your content type manage fields.

Comment: Edited to make it global and not per CT.

Comment: @Benia how did it go?

Comment: Will try and gladly notify...

Comment: Pasted, edited CSS, flushed all cache --- No change... Fields in nodes not effected --- No such div with class "some-wrapper" in DOM.

Comment: @Benia try my updated answer and also you should temporarily change your css to `.some-wrapper { border: solid red; }`

Comment: Sorry if this question sounds pathetic from any reason, isn't the codepiece too long (even if working) to pack these two particular fields to divs in nodes?... :|

Comment: @Benia you're only adding 7 lines of code to the original node.html.twig Furthermore, there is no way to make it shorter and don't worry about it, you're good.

Comment: Oh I wasn't sure at the start if I need to paste everything or override. Now I understand you meant to start from {{ content|without... Thanks !!!

Comment: @Benia, no, you should actually copy everything. All I did was copy the file from `/core/modules/node/templates` node.html.twig and modified it, left out all the comments since they are not needed.