# Block cache not clearing on save?

Tags: 8, blocks, caching

I have some custom block types that display in a region in my site. I have noticed that when changing the contents of these blocks, like an image, text, or title, that when you save and visit the page, the block data is cached and doesn't show the new changes. This is problematic because the client keeps reporting this as a bug, but I can't see where or why it won't update.

Is there a way to have it invalidate when saving a block so that a cache clear isn't necessary? I figured this would be normal behavior, but I have to clear it (while logged in as UID 1 even), and I don't *think* I am doing anything weird or have a contrib module installed that would interfere with this.

Edit: I am *not* using Panels or anything - this is core block.

Comment: Does this block have/use a custom template file, and if yes, can you post the code in your Q?

Comment: It does, but I don't have it on this computer. Will have to update later. In some parts, it checks if `block_content.field_name...` exists before rendering the `content.field_name`. Does that cause it?

Comment: Maybe, but I doubt it. You could also temporarily rename of the template file, so it does not use it, and see if saving works then. Perhaps [this upvoted comment from 4k4](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/208364/packing-taxonomy-fields-into-one-div-not-from-sql#comment-254298) may solve your problem.

Comment: If you not render {{ content }} in a block template you loose the cache data. The main problem here is that unlike other entities `block_content` has not a template and you are forced to use the parent template `block`, which is not really the right place to theme the inside of block_content.

Comment: Still, invalidation should work just fine, cache tags bubble up. For whom exactly does it not update? authenticated users, anonymous users? If it's anonymous, maybe you simply have an external cache (varnish, ..) that doesn't support tag-based invalidation

Comment: The problem in this case is that `block_content:[id]` does not bubble up.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is, that the cache tag `block_content:[id]` does not bubble up and the tag is missing in the cache entry. Without this cache tag the cache entry can't be invalidated when saving a modified custom block.

Here are two workarounds:

**Twig template (Workaround 1)**

If you theme a block template and you render single fields

```
{{ content.field_field1 }}
{{ content.field_field2 }}
```

then you also need to render the rest of `content`:

```
{{ content|without('field_field1', 'field_field2') }}
```

That's because `content` contains the cache tag of the block content entity, which otherwise won't bubble up.

**Preprocess (Workaround 2)**

As an alternative option for rendering `{{ content }}` you can add the cache tag at the top of `variables` in preprocess.

*mytheme.theme*

```
function mytheme_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['base_plugin_id'] == 'block_content') {
    $renderer = \Drupal::service('renderer');
    $renderer->addCacheableDependency($variables, $variables['content']['#block_content']);
  }
}
```

Then you no longer depend on the twig template to render all of `content`.

You'll find in `Drupal\block\BlockViewBuilder::preRender()` more workarounds for issues with bubbling up data from the content render array. You could use this code, which there is only applied in special circumstances, for all cache data from block content to bubble up to the top level:

```
use Drupal\Core\Cache\CacheableMetadata;

function mytheme_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
  $content = $variables['content'];
  CacheableMetadata::createFromRenderArray($variables)
          ->merge(CacheableMetadata::createFromRenderArray($content))
          ->applyTo($variables);
}
```

But I don't know which side effects that would have in other places. If it would be that easy the block view builder would do this already. So it's better to tackle only that specific problem with the one missing tag and use the first version of the preprocess function.

Comment: Turns out thats what it is. I had to do `{{ content.without(args) }}`

Comment: And I can confirm that if you're preprocessing, your code using `addCacheableDependency()` works perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Setting cache max age to 0 saved my day.

```
function MODULE_NAME_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
    if ($variables['base_plugin_id'] == 'block_content') {
        $variables['#cache']['max-age'] = 0;   
    } 
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this prevent all blocks from ever being cached?